# Image is not uploaded or shown in rich text box in voyager

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, voyager

I have a rich text box named service details. There I normally uploaded information and related images of services. But image is not uploaded or shown there.

while I uploaded it shows like below image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution !

My image src link(path) is not right that's why the image is not shown.

Just change

`APP_URL=http://localhost:8000` from `APP_URL=http://localhost` in `.env` file

Answer (score 0):

you just need to read this popular article about voyager image problem that official site is realeased https://voyager.readme.io/docs/using-https-on-your-site

for that just open filesystem.php in config directory and delete line of code `'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',` and in every where just use metho `Voyager::image($user->avatar)`

hope to help you